# fixing the switch multiple cases statement

Tags: java

```
try {
    for (int i = 1; i <= list.size(); i++) {
        String parameter = list.get(i - 1).trim();

        switch (i) {
            case 6:
                scripBO.setErrorCode(Short.parseShort(parameter));
                break;
            case 7:
                scripBO.setBcSeqNo(Long.parseLong(parameter));
                break;
            case 12:
                scripBO.setMsgCount(Long.parseLong(parameter));
                msgcount= scripBO.getMsgCount();
                break;
            case 13:
            case 16:
            case 19:
            case 22:
            case 25:
            case 28:
            case 31:
            case 34:
            case 37:
            case 40:
            case 43:
            case 46: // and multiple cases.. 
                tokenval = scripBO.setTokenNumber(Long.parseLong(parameter));
                break;
```

Comment: it could help if you explain what exactly you want to fix

Comment: Try to explain your question properly.

Comment: Maybe, a simple `default` would suffice, if you had only a small amount of options that needs special handling. But that's not sure until you show us more requirements and code.

Comment: I highly recommend you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are handling each third number starting from 13. If you want to decrease the number of `case` statements you can create an `if` outside of `switch` to handle these numbers:

```
switch (i) {
   case 6: ...
   case 7: ...
   case 12: ...
}
if (i >= 13 && i % 3 == 1) { // 13, 16, 19...
   tokenval = scripBO.setTokenNumber(Long.parseLong(parameter));
}
```